# How to get Realtek ALC887-VD to play any sound or be recognized in Debian 11 (fresh install)?

Tags: debian, audio, realtek, bugs

The title is self-explanatory: after a fresh installation of Debian 11, there is no sound at all.

The computer went to service with a burnt power supply, it was discovered that the motherboard was burnt too, and when it returned it came back with a motherboard whose chip, it seems, is not recognized by Debian, nor by Ubuntu (which I also tried to install).

When I did a fresh install of Debian 11, the result is that there is no sound at all. No beep, no noise, no buzz, nothing, absolutely nothing. In the "Settings" I can see a "Dummy Output", and nothing else. When playing .mp3 files, the volume indicators in the equalizer move, but there is no sound.

The chip is the Realtek ALC887-VD. I saw that there are several solutions available on the internet dealing with this specific hardware, but none of them worked.

Due to character limitation, I will put in the comments the commands I ran, and their results.

What can I do to get the sound in Debian working again?

**$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio**

```
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1c20] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1c20]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

**$ aplay -l**

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC887-VD Digital [ALC887-VD Digital]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

**$ lshw -c sound**

```
*-multimedia              
       description: Audio device
       product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1b
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
       version: 05
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:27 memory:f7c00000-f7c03fff
```

**$ lsmod | grep 's(ou)?nd'**

```
Module                  Size  Used by
snd_seq                86016  0
snd_seq_device         16384  1 snd_seq
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     73728  1
snd_hda_codec_realtek   159744  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    98304  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ledtrig_audio          16384  1 snd_hda_codec_generic
snd_hda_intel          57344  4
snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  1 snd_hda_intel
soundwire_intel        45056  1 snd_intel_dspcfg
soundwire_generic_allocation    16384  1 soundwire_intel
snd_soc_core          315392  1 soundwire_intel
snd_compress           32768  1 snd_soc_core
soundwire_cadence      36864  1 soundwire_intel
snd_hda_codec         172032  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core          110592  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
soundwire_bus          90112  3 soundwire_intel,soundwire_generic_allocation,soundwire_cadence
snd_pcm               135168  8 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_core
snd_timer              49152  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                   110592  19 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm
soundcore              16384  1 snd
```

**$ speaker-test -c2 -t wave -D hw:1,0**

```
speaker-test 1.2.4

Playback device is hw:1,0
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 2 channels
WAV file(s)
ALSA lib pcm_hw.c:1829:(_snd_pcm_hw_open) Invalid value for card
Playback open error: -2,Arquivo ou diretório inexistente
```

**$ pactl stat**

```
Currently in use: 12 blocks containing 111,0 KiB bytes total.
Allocated during whole lifetime: 675722 blocks containing 1,0 GiB bytes total.
Tamanho do cache para amostragem: 24,0 KiB
```

**$ pulseaudio -vvvv**

```
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_NICE, (31, 31)) failed: Operação não permitida
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_RTPRIO, (9, 9)) failed: Operação não permitida
D: [pulseaudio] core-rtclock.c: Timer slack is set to 50 us.
D: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: RealtimeKit worked.
I: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Successfully gained nice level -11.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: This is PulseAudio 14.2
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compilation CFLAGS: -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/pulseaudio-eJtUKc/pulseaudio-14.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall -W -Wextra -pipe -Wno-long-long -Wno-overlength-strings -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations -Wundef -Wformat=2 -Wlogical-op -Wsign-compare -Wformat-security -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wformat-nonliteral -Wpointer-arith -Winit-self -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wfloat-equal -Wmissing-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-noreturn -Wshadow -Wendif-labels -Wcast-align -Wstrict-aliasing -Wwrite-strings -Wno-unused-parameter -fno-common -fdiagnostics-show-option -fdiagnostics-color=auto
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running on host: Linux x86_64 5.10.0-11-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.92-1 (2022-01-18)
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Found 4 CPUs.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Page size is 4096 bytes
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compiled with Valgrind support: no
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in valgrind mode: no
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in VM: no
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running from build tree: no
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Optimized build: yes
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: FASTPATH defined, only fast path asserts disabled.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Machine ID is c2b85c79587e4109a5887f6571d1d2b1.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using runtime directory /run/user/1000/pulse.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using state directory /home/fernanda/.config/pulse.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using modules directory /usr/lib/pulse-14.2/modules.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in system mode: no
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() falhou.
```

**$ fuser -v -u /dev/snd/***

```
                     USUÁRIO     PID ACESSO COMANDO
/dev/snd/controlC0:  fernanda  10038 F.... (fernanda)pulseaudio
/dev/snd/pcmC0D1p:   fernanda  10038 F...m (fernanda)pulseaudio
```

**$ alsa-info**

```
http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=0fcdb88ddbb6177a4ba074c5d38628a493bf0de6
```

**$ pulseaudio**

```
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() falhou.
```

**$ rm  ~/.config/pulse/* && reboot**

```
No results
```

**$ echo "options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf**

```
No results
```

**$ echo "blacklist snd_soc_skl" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf**

```
No results
```

**$ sudo usermod -a -G audio USERNAME**

```
No results (yes, I've changed USERNAME for my real username before running the command)
```

I can get sound working by running:

```
$ pulseaudio --kill
$ pulseaudio --start
```

I made a startup script with these two commands, so I wouldn't have to remember them at each new reboot.

But that doesn't say anything about the causes of the problem. The Debian 11 installation was new, fresh. There was no reason, at least in theory, for pulseaudio not to work.

What is the cause of the problem? Does anyone have any guidance to give?

Comment: If killing and restarting pulseaudio gets sound working (important information that belongs in the question), then in principle you have working sound. Now you need to debug why it's not working initially, which is *really* difficult to do in Q&A format.

Answer (score 1):

I simply cannot believe how simple it was to stumble upon a temporary solution:

```
$ pulseaudio --kill
$ pulseaudio --start
```

And voilá! Sound working again.

I had already tried `pulseaudio --kill` before, but I had no idea on how to restart it.

I made a startup script with these two commands, so I wouldn't have to remember them at each new reboot.

But that doesn't say anything about the causes of the problem. The Debian 11 installation was new, fresh. There was no reason, at least in theory, for pulseaudio not to work.

What is the cause of the problem? Does anyone have any guidance to give?